# How can I hide source of spot lamp and keep the emission for the visible part

Tags: light

I want to make converge the lens of a modeled spotlight with a spot lamp. So as to match the diameter of the lens and the base the spot lamp, I moved the lamp further inside the object but then, I have no emission since the base of the spot lamp is where the source of light is located.

Since there is no way I can change the diameter at the source of the spot lamp, I was wondering if there was a way to mask / crop / hide that part and keep the emission for the visible part.

I tried different ways without satisfying results.
Any help for 2.79 and 2.8 are welcome!
[image]

Comment: I don't understand.  If the problem is the bottom of your cylinder, delete the bottom face.  If the problem is the top of the cylinder, make the cylinder longer.

Comment: you can also look up transparent shader and separate the bottom shade face into a new object from edit mode if you need to keep the face of the bottom of the lamp for some reason, though deleting it in edit mode seems correct as stated. adjust the clip start and end point as another alternative if placing in the lamp shade.

Comment: Thank you, more options than I would have hoped for

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cycles, you can disable shadows for the cylinder so the light can pass through it:

[image]

However, like this, the entire object won't cast any shadows which may be undesirable, so you could delete the face of the cylinder and add a new circle object in place of it which has its shadow disabled.

In EEVEE, you can disable shadows per material, so you can apply an emissive material for example to the face and have its shadow disabled:

[image]

Result with EEVEE:
[image]
Result with cycles:
[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)